# How do I get out of this recursive function when n = -1?

Tags: recursion, scheme

The problem I have to solve is how many oranges are in a pyramid if each level has 2^n oranges. I think I have the basis for the solution, however this is an infinite recursion. How do I get out of this function when n has reached -1 and display the solution? This is in scheme.

I've used this to help me set up what I need:

```
(+ (expt 2 0) (+ (expt 2 1) (+ (expt 2 2) (expt 2 3))))
```

3 is arbitrary and I only used it to help me write out the solution

```
(define oranges
    (lambda (n)
    (+ (expt 2 n) (oranges(- n 1)))))
```

Running this will not work because it is an infinite loop.

Comment: Note that you don't really need a recursive computation. There is a simple way to calculate this, which is very closely related to the binary representation of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're writing a recursive procedure, it's *mandatory* to have a base case: it's the exit point of the recursion, otherwise it'll loop infinitely. Ask yourself: when should my procedure end? what should I return in that case?

In your case is simple, you literally wrote the answer in the title: how should we handle the case when `n = -1`? (or `-2`, or `-3`...?) Just return a meaningful value! I'd suggest `0`, because we're doing an addition.

Now, in your code *ask* with an `if` expression whether we're in a value when we should return, and then return `0` - otherwise do the recursive step, which will eventually reach the base case. This is what I mean:

```
(define oranges
  (lambda (n)
    (if (< n 0)
        0
        (+ (expt 2 n) (oranges (- n 1))))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(oranges 3)
=> 15
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make a recursive function, there are different parts that are compulsory. You need the general case and the basic cases. You have forgotten the basic cases also known as exit condition. Your exit condition is n = 0, so your program will be:

```
(define (oranges n) 
     (cond [(= n 0) 1] 
       [else (+(expt 2 n)(oranges(- n 1)))] 
     ) 
)
```

Tested:

```
   (oranges 1)
=> 3
   (oranges 0)
=> 1
   (oranges 2)
=> 7
```